# My SASS is compiling but not working properly

Tags: html, css, sass

I was working on a frontend mentor challenge with coder coder video on Free Code Camp, and she was using SASS. I'm not familiar with compiling SASS into CSS file but I tried to. Anyway when I'm writing changes, it's getting compiled but without any changes.

Like in the fonts file in globals folder I wrote this line:

```
:root {
    --font-inter: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}
```

and then in the same folder in the boilerplate file, I wrote:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: var(--font-inter);
    background: var(--background);
    color: var(--text-color);
  }
```

and wrote:

```
@forward 'fonts';
@forward "boilerplate";
```

in the index.scss file in that folder. I checked that everything wrtten above had been compiled to the style.css file in the root folder.

Oh wait a second, as I'm writing this question I remembered to check if I linked the css file to the html file. This was my real problem.

I think writing this question helped to lead me to articulate my thoughts.

Comment: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward/ You might want to use @\use instead of @\forward